# Backtransform variables in ggeffects (logistic regression)

Tags: logistic, back-transformation

I am running a logistic regression. Two variables are transformed for linearity with the logit of the outcome.

```
var1<-w^(-0.5) 
var2<-t^2
m1 <- glm(Dep ~ var1 + var2, family=binomial())
```

If plot probabilities in ggeffects, the variables are on the transformed scale.

```
library(ggeffects)
library(car)
p<-ggpredict(m1, terms=c("var1[all]", "var2[0.01,0.09,0.25]"))
plot(p, ci = TRUE, colors = c("system")) + geom_line(size=2) +  labs(colour = "")
```

To solve this, I transformed var1 back:

```
p$x <- 1/(p$x)^2
```

The question is now how to transform var2 back. I have back-transformed the three fixed values of var2 manually:

```
0.01^0.5 = 0.1
0.09^0.5 = 0.3
0.25^0.25 = 0.5 
p$group<-recode(p$group, "0.01='0.1';0.09 ='0.3';0.25 ='0.5'")
```

The final plot:

```
p<-ggpredict(m1, terms=c("var1[all]", "var2[0.01,0.09,0.25]"))
p$x <- 1/(p$x)^2
p$group<-recode(p$group, "0.01='0.1';0.09 ='0.3';0.25 ='0.5'")
plot(p, ci = TRUE, colors = c("system")) +
geom_line(size=2) +  labs(colour = "")
```

However, is this way of transforming variables back to their original scale correct?

Link to file:  https://files.cargocollective.com/c711793/df.csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be transforming and back-transforming when you can include those transformations as part of the model. That way, you can just request values of the raw predictors and `ggpredict()` will respect those values.

So, instead of creating new variables, you would include the transformations as terms in your `glm()` call, then supply the values to `ggpredict()` on the scale of the original variables in the `terms` argument. This is what this might look like:

```r
library(ggeffects); library(ggplot2)
d <- read.csv("https://files.cargocollective.com/c711793/df.csv")

m1 <- glm(Dep ~ I(w^(-.5)) + I(t^2), family = binomial(), data = d)
p <- ggpredict(m1, terms=list(w = seq(1, 33, length = 51),
                              t = c(0.1,0.3,0.5)))
plot(p, ci = TRUE, colors = c("system")) + geom_line(linewidth=2) + labs(colour = "")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Well-explained, thank you. I had a feeling my approach was not fully correct.